# What does disabling `CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB` do?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I'm attempting to get raw camera output with opencv. If I read an image normally I get a 640x480x3 image:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
>>> _, im = cap.read()
>>> im.shape
(480, 640, 3)
```

If I disable `cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB` then I get a strangely sized array, the end of which is always zeros:

```
>>> cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)
True
>>> _, im = cap.read()
>>> im.shape
(1, 614400)
>>> cv2.imshow('im', im.reshape((960, 640))); cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The resulting 'image' is:

[image]

What do I do with this data to get an actual image from it?

Answer (score 1):

From `videoio.hpp`:

> CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB   =16, //!< Boolean flags indicating whether images should be converted to RGB.

For your example, you need to decode the 1D data.

```
cv2.imshow('im', cv2.imdecode(im,-1))
```