Object Detection from Thermal Camera (USB) weird error
I am super new to python but wanted to try and make a cool vision system for a project I am doing on my car. Initially I was going to use the Arducam IMX462 with a Coral TPU but some issues came up with the PI 5 where I can't seem to get any of the work around to work to make the Coral TPU work on python 3.11. So we have shifted courses to now use a Thermal Camera as our camera which I think will work out better in the long run. This also mean I could go back down to the ras Pi 4 and get the USB TPU and have it work and get about 15/20 fps which should be more than enough for this project. My only issue is since there is now native support for thermal cameras I am using a program that was created for this model (Topdon TC001) and it works great. My only issue is when I add the object det4ection part I get an error that I am not familial with.
This is the error I get
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 2, 480, 640] to have 3 channels, but got 2 channels instead
Not I think this might have to do with how the thermal image is processed but I am not 100% sure. I was hoping this route would work as this would be amazing for night time which is the only area where I need the object detection to really work. Any help would be much appreciated on figuring out why that error happens. Granted I know you guy probably wont have this thermal camera to test on yourselves but any help still greatly appreciated.
Source Code for the Thermal camera here Github
-Also apologies if the code doesn't show up right, I have never used stack overflow before.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time
import io
from ultralytics import YOLO

#We need to know if we are running on the Pi, because openCV behaves a little oddly on all the builds!
#https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/detect-that-a-python-program-is-running-on-the-pi
def is_raspberrypi():
    try:
        with io.open('/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model', 'r') as m:
            if 'raspberry pi' in m.read().lower(): return True
    except Exception: pass
    return False

isPi = is_raspberrypi()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--device", type=int, default=0, help="Video Device number e.g. 0, use v4l2-ctl --list-devices")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.device:
    dev = args.device
else:
    dev = 0
    
#init video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video'+str(dev), cv2.CAP_V4L)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#pull in the video but do NOT automatically convert to RGB, else it breaks the temperature data!
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108721/opencv-setting-videocap-property-to-cap-prop-convert-rgb-generates-weird-boolean
if isPi == True:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0.0)
else:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)

#256x192 General settings
width = 256 #Sensor width
height = 192 #sensor height
scale = 3 #scale multiplier
newWidth = width*scale 
newHeight = height*scale
alpha = 1.0 # Contrast control (1.0-3.0)
colormap = 5
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
dispFullscreen = False
cv2.namedWindow('Thermal',cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Thermal', newWidth,newHeight)
rad = 0 #blur radius
threshold = 2
hud = False
recording = False
elapsed = "00:00:00"
snaptime = "None"

# Initialize YOLO model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

def rec():
    now = time.strftime("%Y%m%d--%H%M%S")
    #do NOT use mp4 here, it is flakey!
    videoOut = cv2.VideoWriter(now+'output.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),25, (newWidth,newHeight))
    return(videoOut)

def snapshot(heatmap):
    #I would put colons in here, but it Win throws a fit if you try and open them!
    now = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") 
    snaptime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    cv2.imwrite("TC001"+now+".png", heatmap)
    return snaptime
 

while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        imdata,thdata = np.array_split(frame, 2)
        #now parse the data from the bottom frame and convert to temp!
        #https://www.eevblog.com/forum/thermal-imaging/infiray-and-their-p2-pro-discussion/200/
        #Huge props to LeoDJ for figuring out how the data is stored and how to compute temp from it.
        #grab data from the center pixel...
        hi = thdata[96][128][0]
        lo = thdata[96][128][1]
        #print(hi,lo)
        lo = lo*256
        rawtemp = hi+lo
        #print(rawtemp)
        temp = (rawtemp/64)-273.15
        temp = round(temp,2)
        #print(temp)
        #break

        #find the max temperature in the frame
        lomax = thdata[...,1].max()
        posmax = thdata[...,1].argmax()
        #since argmax returns a linear index, convert back to row and col
        mcol,mrow = divmod(posmax,width)
        himax = thdata[mcol][mrow][0]
        lomax=lomax*256
        maxtemp = himax+lomax
        maxtemp = (maxtemp/64)-273.15
        maxtemp = round(maxtemp,2)


        #find the lowest temperature in the frame
        lomin = thdata[...,1].min()
        posmin = thdata[...,1].argmin()
        #since argmax returns a linear index, convert back to row and col
        lcol,lrow = divmod(posmin,width)
        himin = thdata[lcol][lrow][0]
        lomin=lomin*256
        mintemp = himin+lomin
        mintemp = (mintemp/64)-273.15
        mintemp = round(mintemp,2)

        #find the average temperature in the frame
        loavg = thdata[...,1].mean()
        hiavg = thdata[...,0].mean()
        loavg=loavg*256
        avgtemp = loavg+hiavg
        avgtemp = (avgtemp/64)-273.15
        avgtemp = round(avgtemp,2)
        
        # Convert the real image to RGB
        bgr = cv2.cvtColor(imdata, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUYV)
        # Contrast
        bgr = cv2.convertScaleAbs(bgr, alpha=alpha)  # Contrast
        # bicubic interpolate, upscale and blur
        bgr = cv2.resize(bgr, (newWidth, newHeight), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)  # Scale up!
        if rad > 0:
            bgr = cv2.blur(bgr, (rad, rad))
        # YOLO object detection
        detections = model(imdata, stream=False)
    
        if colormap == 5:
            heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(bgr, cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)
            cmapText = 'Bone'
        for detection in detections:
            x, y, w, h, conf, cls = detection
            cv2.rectangle(imdata, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(imdata, f'{cls}: {conf:.2f}', (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(heatmap, (int(newWidth / 2), int(newHeight / 2) + 20), \
                 (int(newWidth / 2), int(newHeight / 2) - 20), (255, 255, 255), 2)  # vline
        cv2.line(heatmap, (int(newWidth / 2) + 20, int(newHeight / 2)), \
                 (int(newWidth / 2) - 20, int(newHeight / 2)), (255, 255, 255), 2)  # hline

        cv2.line(heatmap, (int(newWidth / 2), int(newHeight / 2) + 20), \
                 (int(newWidth / 2), int(newHeight / 2) - 20), (0, 0, 0), 1)  # vline
        cv2.line(heatmap, (int(newWidth / 2) + 20, int(newHeight / 2)), \
                 (int(newWidth / 2) - 20, int(newHeight / 2)), (0, 0, 0), 1)  # hline
        # show temp
        cv2.putText(heatmap, str(temp) + ' C', (int(newWidth / 2) + 10, int(newHeight / 2) - 10), \
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(heatmap, str(temp) + ' C', (int(newWidth / 2) + 10, int(newHeight / 2) - 10), \
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        # Draw bounding boxes on the frame
        

        if maxtemp > avgtemp+threshold:
            cv2.circle(heatmap, (mrow*scale, mcol*scale), 5, (0,0,0), 2)
            cv2.circle(heatmap, (mrow*scale, mcol*scale), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
            cv2.putText(heatmap,str(maxtemp)+' C', ((mrow*scale)+10, (mcol*scale)+5),\
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,(0,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(heatmap,str(maxtemp)+' C', ((mrow*scale)+10, (mcol*scale)+5),\
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,(0, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #display floating min temp
        if mintemp < avgtemp-threshold:
            cv2.circle(heatmap, (lrow*scale, lcol*scale), 5, (0,0,0), 2)
            cv2.circle(heatmap, (lrow*scale, lcol*scale), 5, (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(heatmap,str(mintemp)+' C', ((lrow*scale)+10, (lcol*scale)+5),\
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,(0,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(heatmap,str(mintemp)+' C', ((lrow*scale)+10, (lcol*scale)+5),\
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,(0, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #display image
        cv2.imshow('Thermal',heatmap)
'''
        if recording == True:
            elapsed = (time.time() - start)
            elapsed = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed)) 
            #print(elapsed)
            videoOut.write(heatmap)

        keyPress = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if keyPress == ord('a'): #Increase blur radius
            rad += 1
        if keyPress == ord('z'): #Decrease blur radius
            rad -= 1
            if rad <= 0:
                rad = 0

        if keyPress == ord('s'): #Increase threshold
            threshold += 1
        if keyPress == ord('x'): #Decrease threashold
            threshold -= 1
            if threshold <= 0:
                threshold = 0

        if keyPress == ord('d'): #Increase scale
            scale += 1
            if scale >=5:
                scale = 5
            newWidth = width*scale
            newHeight = height*scale
            if dispFullscreen == False and isPi == False:
                cv2.resizeWindow('Thermal', newWidth,newHeight)
        if keyPress == ord('c'): #Decrease scale
            scale -= 1
            if scale <= 1:
                scale = 1
            newWidth = width*scale
            newHeight = height*scale
            if dispFullscreen == False and isPi == False:
                cv2.resizeWindow('Thermal', newWidth,newHeight)

        if keyPress == ord('q'): #enable fullscreen
            dispFullscreen = True
            cv2.namedWindow('Thermal',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
            cv2.setWindowProperty('Thermal',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        if keyPress == ord('w'): #disable fullscreen
            dispFullscreen = False
            cv2.namedWindow('Thermal',cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
            cv2.setWindowProperty('Thermal',cv2.WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE,cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
            cv2.resizeWindow('Thermal', newWidth,newHeight)

        if keyPress == ord('f'): #contrast+
            alpha += 0.1
            alpha = round(alpha,1)#fix round error
            if alpha >= 3.0:
                alpha=3.0
        if keyPress == ord('v'): #contrast-
            alpha -= 0.1
            alpha = round(alpha,1)#fix round error
            if alpha<=0:
                alpha = 0.0


        if keyPress == ord('h'):
            if hud==True:
                hud=False
            elif hud==False:
                hud=True

        if keyPress == ord('m'): #m to cycle through color maps
            colormap += 1
            if colormap == 11:
                colormap = 0

        if keyPress == ord('r') and recording == False: #r to start reording
            videoOut = rec()
            recording = True
            start = time.time()
        if keyPress == ord('t'): #f to finish reording
            recording = False
            elapsed = "00:00:00"

        if keyPress == ord('p'): #f to finish reording
            snaptime = snapshot(heatmap)

        if keyPress == ord('q'):
            break
            capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
'''


Problem Solved. I majorly overthought what needed to be done. Since I wasn't interested in any of the temp data, as in getting the max temps or min temps, I didn't need to base the code off the one I posted above. I was able to use the USB thermal camera as is with only a bit of code to get rid of the dual image that was displayed. Would still be curious if anyone knows why the above code didn't work.
